# AJAX call to GET data from a Django view as JSON, then POST it to another view

Tags: python, jquery, json, ajax, django

I have a Django view function similar to the following, which scrapes data and returns it as JSON:

```
def get_data(request):
    #scraping code here
    scraped_data = {"Name": "John"}
    return JsonResponse(scraped_data)
```

I need AJAX assigned to `.submit` method of a form that calls this view using "GET" method, gets the `scraped_data` and sends it to another view for further processing.

I would appreciate if someone would help me develop the following skeleton code of such AJAX call:

```
$("#my_form").submit(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "/get_data",
           data: // need scraped_data here, how do I phrase it?
           success: function(data)
           {
               //send scraped_data to another Django view, possibly using jQuery ".post"?; 
           }
     });
});
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `python` or `django`. removed the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with following script.

```
$("#my_form").submit(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "/get_data",
           success: function(data)
           {
            $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/post_data", //your post url
             dataType: "JSON",
             data: data,
             success: function(response)
             {
              alert(response);
             }
            });
           }
     });
});
```

I don't code in Python but I know how to do it from AJAX side. So basically you get the data from first AJAX in json format, Now in success of first AJAX you can post the data using another AJAX using POST method. Add `dataType: "JSON"` will allow you to transfer json data from view to controller. In your controller you will get the data `{"Name": "John"}`. Hope this will help.

Comment: you might want to add `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting and then do a `$(this).submit()` in the end.